# How to get last 31 days Visits record of user

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, analytics

I'm trying to show this month Profile views to the user, now my code works perfect if I'm showing from 1st of the date till today date, but problem arises when the user register on my site, Let's suppose user registered on 26 march
Now I'm not able to show 0 views for past 25 days because his data doesn't exist in the database. Let me show you my code

```
    $year = date("Y");
    $month = date("m");
    $number = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
    $q = $db->getRows("SELECT date AS dates, COUNT(user_id) AS view 
                        FROM profile_analytics 
                        WHERE user_id = ? 
                        AND date BETWEEN ? AND ? 
                        GROUP BY `date` 
                        ORDER BY `date`", 
                PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, 
                [Profile::getid(), 
                "$year-$month-1", 
                "$year-$month-$number"]);
    $i = 0;

    while ($i <= $number) {
        $i++;
        $a = $i - 1;
        if (isset($q[$a]['dates'])) {

            if ($q[$a]['dates'] != "$year-$month-$i") {

                $click = 0;
            } else {

                $click = $q[$a]['view'];
            }
        } else {

            $click = 0;
        }

        $array [] = $click;
    }

    return implode(', ', $array);
}
```

This is what I get from the database

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dates] => 2017-03-25
            [view] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [dates] => 2017-03-26
            [view] => 15
        )

)
```

After all above this is what I get

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I know my method is wrong, but I need better one

This is the new response I received

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dates] => 2017-03-01
            [view] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [dates] => 2017-03-02
            [view] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [dates] => 2017-03-03
            [view] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [dates] => 2017-03-25
            [view] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [dates] => 2017-03-26
            [view] => 13
        )

)
```

This is what I got after implode

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1
```

Comment: Do you just want to show `99 views this period` or do you want to show `1 views on the 25th` then `15 views on the 26th` In other words _Show us what yu want the output to look like on the page_

Comment: Please share the value `$year` and `$month`.

Comment: I want to show total view of each day and if that day doesn't exist in database than it should display 0

Comment: So you dont want the date, just a list of comma seperated numbers

Comment: yes i just want the views of that each day in month, so that i can show it in graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function xxx()
{

    $year           = date("Y");
    $month          = date("m");
    $days_in_month  = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);

    $q = $db->getRows("SELECT date AS dates, COUNT(user_id) AS view 
                        FROM profile_analytics 
                        WHERE user_id = ? 
                        AND date BETWEEN ? AND ? 
                        GROUP BY `date` 
                        ORDER BY `date`", 
                PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, 
                [Profile::getid(), 
                "$year-$month-1", 
                "$year-$month-$days_in_month"]);

    // for each day in the month init the totals array
    // one for every day of the month to ZERO
    $views = array_fill(1,(int)$days_in_month,0);

    // foreach date that someone actually viewed this users profile
    // put a real count in the $views array
    foreach ( $q as $viewed ) {
        $the_day = (int)substr($viewed['dates'], -2);  // get the day from the date
        $views[$the_day] = $viewed['view'];
    }
    return implode(', ', $views);
}
```

If we dummy up some data in the format you say is coming back from the database query ...

```
function xxx()
{

    $year           = date("Y");
    $month          = date("m");
    $days_in_month  = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);

    $q = [
            ['dates' => '2017-03-01' , 'view' => 1],
            ['dates' => '2017-03-02' , 'view' => 1],
            ['dates' => '2017-03-03' , 'view' => 1],
            ['dates' => '2017-03-10' , 'view' => 1],
            ['dates' => '2017-03-25' , 'view' => 5],
            ['dates' => '2017-03-26' , 'view' => 10]
        ];

    // for each day in the month init the totals array
    // one for every day of the month to ZERO
    $views = array_fill(1,(int)$days_in_month,0);

    // foreach date that someone actually viewed this users profile
    // put a real count in the $views array
    foreach ( $q as $viewed ) {
        $the_day = (int)substr($viewed['dates'], -2);  // get the day from the date
        $views[$the_day] = $viewed['view'];
    }
    return implode(', ', $views);
}

$s = xxx();
print $s;
```

The output is

```
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: Thanks it Worked, but I'm getting `[31] => 0 [-1] => 2` Why there is -1?

Comment: Hmmmm dont know, let me look at it

Comment: Typo, fixed last line `return implode(', ', $views);`

Comment: now i added some dummy data into database and two views for `2017-03-01` and `2017-03-02` but it still showing 0 for those days

Comment: Then we had better look more closely at what the query is returning

Comment: See this line with the fix `$the_day = (int)substr($viewed['dates'], -2);`

Comment: Thanks, Worked perfectly